# How can I have a Macro like recording feature for PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a Qt `tablewidget` and other Qt widgets adjoining it. What I am looking for a Automatic script generator that records all the actions that I would perform on the table or other Qt widgets. I had also worked with Enthought and they have a wonderful apptool `enthought.scripting` that helps me with the same but only for traits objects. I would like to do the same on PyQt widgets but dont know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`eventFilter`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qobject.html#eventFilter) method from your [`QApplication`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qapplication.html) instance.

Comment: The documentation claims that using an `eventFilter` with `QApplication` can capture all events, but in my own testing I found that some events would be dropped (e.g. if some *other* event filter removes it first).  I found that subclassing QApplication and overriding `QApplication.notify()` was the best way to ensure you are getting **all** events in the application.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those ideas that seems so natural, it makes you wonder why there isn't already a library out there that does it.

Well, it turns out that writing something that gets you 80% of the solution is pretty straightforward, especially if your app is small.  But implementing a recording/playback system that works for a large app with a diverse array of widgets is quite a pain.

I wrote a library that does its best to solve this problem.  It's full of hacks, and the code is still very immature (I just pushed the repo to github today), but you might get some ideas.  Heck, if you're lucky, you might even be able to use it without any changes:

https://github.com/stuarteberg/eventcapture

There's no documentation yet.  I plan to explain all the tricks to get this working, and probably clean up the code a bit.  For now, you can at least get started by trying the demo as described in the Readme.